# chrome android setting width to 100%

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, width

I've got a problem with the css on android with the chrome browser

what i do in css is:

```
html{
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

body{
background-color: rgba(101,122,151,0.8);
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

header {
width: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
color: yellow;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: left;
}
```

and in the javascript i outprint the widths of the body and header

```
alert($('header').width());
alert($('body').width());
```

it is showing me the body width is 980 and the header width is 340
but I don't understand why. can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: A screenshot or a link to a reproduction would be nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When loading a webpage on a mobile browser, the browser will assume the site is designed for a larger screen and gives a larger viewport than the device so the user can zoom in on the content.

If you want the width of the device, you need to set the viewport size which can be done with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

There is more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_basics

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Updated to MDN, which should be a more reliable source of information.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you set max-width: 100% and then width: 100% means that width will override max-width, so you can remove max-width. Besides what's the point of setting min/max the same as width?

Second, if you set body width 100% then body takes max width of the viewport. So the question is what's the viewport size?

Comment: I set min-width, because I thought it would work using this instead of width, but it doesn't.
I think the viewport has the full size of the browser window, because the body has a width of 980px which is the full width of the browser window.
the background color of the body is over the whole screen, so the body has the width of 100%

Comment: Try to set margin: 0 and border: none for body and header.

Comment: I change them, but doesn't helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set min-width to 100% on the body?

Any reason you use position on html and body, and not header also?